# Hide keyboard with dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

The user taps a button to bring up a view controller with a keyboard. In this case, the keyboard slides up *with* the view controller so it looks like the keyboard is fixed into the view controller.

Upon completion, the user hits "done" or whatever, the keyboard is dismissed, and view controller slides away with `dismissViewControllerAnimated`. However, even though both hide, the keyboard hides at a slightly lower rate than the view controller. This looks slightly strange, in my case, and doesn't go along with the idea that the keyboard is fixed within the VC.

How can I fix this? Somehow, **I need to make the keyboard slide down as the same rate as the view controller**. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You will have an easier time doing it the other way: making the view controller go along with the keyboard. That's easy, because (1) the keyboard tells you its animation duration and curve, and (2) you can customize the view controller animation to match it.